# Unsuccessful in trying to reuse Java client socket

Tags: java, sockets, http, servlets

I have a software driver which communicates with a third-party controller; I have an API for using the latter but no visibility of its source code, and the supplier is not co-operative in trying to improve things!

The situation is as follows.

To send a request to the controller, I send an XML packet as the content of an HTTP POST to a servlet, which then sends me the response. The original code, implemented by a previous developer, works stably using java.net.Socket. However, our driver is implemented such that a new socket is created for EVERY request sent and, if the driver gets busy, the third-party controller struggles to keep up in terms of socket handling. In fact, their support guy said to me: "You really need to leave 5 seconds between each request...". This simply isn't commercially acceptable.

To improve performance, I wanted to try leaving our end of the socket open and reusing the socket pretty much indefinitely (given that connections can drop unexpectedly of course, but that's the least of my concerns and is manageable). However, whatever I seem to do, the effect is that if I use Comms.getSocket(false), a new socket is created for each request and everything works OK but bottlenecks when busy. If I use Comms.getSocket(true), the following happens:

- Controller is sent first request
- Controller responds to first request
- Controller is sent second request (maybe 5 seconds later)
- Controller never responds to second request or anything after it
- postRequest() keeps getting called: for the first 12 seconds, the console outputs "Input shut down ? false" but, after that, the code no longer reaches there and doesn't get past the bw.write() and bw.flush() calls.

The controller allows both HTTP 1.0 and 1.1 but their docs say zilch about keep-alive. I've tried both  and the code below shows that I've added Keep-Alive headers as well but the controller, as server, I'm guessing is ignoring them -- I don't think I have any way of knowing, do I ? When in HTTP 1.0 mode, the controller certainly returns a "Connection: close" but doesn't do that in HTTP 1.1 mode.

**The likelihood is then that the server side is insisting on a "one socket per request" approach.**

**However, I wondered if I might be doing anything wrong (or missing something) in the following code to achieve what I want:**

```
private String postRequest() throws IOException {
    String resp = null;
    String logMsg;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder sbWrite = new StringBuilder();
    Comms comms = getComms();
    Socket socket = comms.getSocket(true);
    BufferedReader br = comms.getReader();
    BufferedWriter bw = comms.getWriter();
    if (null != socket) {
        System.out.println("Socket closed ? " + socket.isClosed());
        System.out.println("Socket bound ? " + socket.isBound());
        System.out.println("Socket connected ? " + socket.isConnected());

        // Write the request
        sbWrite
            .append("POST /servlet/receiverServlet HTTP/1.1\r\n")
            .append("Host: 192.168.200.100\r\n")
            .append("Connection: Keep-Alive\r\n")
            .append("Keep-Alive: timeout=10\r\n")
            .append("Content-Type: text/xml\r\n")
            .append("Content-Length: " + requestString.length() + "\r\n\r\n")
            .append(requestString);
        System.out.println("Writing:\n" + sbWrite.toString());
        bw.write(sbWrite.toString());
        bw.flush();

        // Read the response
        System.out.println("Input shut down ? " + socket.isInputShutdown());
        String line;
        boolean flag = false;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println("Line: <" + line + ">");
            if (flag) sb.append(line);
            if (line.isEmpty()) flag = true;
        }
        resp = sb.toString();
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Socket not available");
    }
    return resp; // Another method will parse the response
}
```

To ease testing, I provide the socket using an extra Comms helper class and a method called getSocket(boolean reuse) where I can choose to always create a new socket or reuse the one that Comms creates for me, as follows:

```
public Comms(String ip, int port) {
    this.ip = ip;
    this.port = port;
    initSocket();
}

private void initSocket() {
    try {
        socket = new Socket(ip, port);
        socket.setKeepAlive(true);
        socket.setPerformancePreferences(1, 0, 0);
        socket.setReuseAddress(true);
        bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        System.out.println("@@@ CREATED NEW SOCKET");
    }
    catch (UnknownHostException uhe) {
        System.out.println("@@@ UNKNOWN HOST FOR SOCKET");
    }
    catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println("@@@ SOCKET I/O EXCEPTION");
    }
}

public BufferedReader getReader() { return br; }

public BufferedWriter getWriter() { return bw; }

public Socket getSocket(boolean reuse) {
    if (! reuse) initSocket();
    return socket;
}
```

Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 0):

If we assume that keep-alive thing is working as expected, I think the line `while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)` is a faulty one, as this is kind of infinity loop.

`readline()` returns `null` when there is no more data to read, e.g. a `EOF`, or when server/client closes the connection, that will break-down your reusing socket solution, since an open stream will never cause a `null` to a `readLine()` call, but blocking.

You need to fix the alg about reading a response (why not using implemented http client?), checking `content-length`, and when read the amount of required data from body, go for next loop by keeping the socket alive.
After that setting `flag` to `true`, you have to know what kind of data should be read(considering mime/content-type), besides that, the length of data, so reading data using `readLine()` may not be a good practice here.

Also make sure server allow for persistence connection, by checking if it respects it by responsing the same `connection:keep-alive` header.